# java SimpleDateFormat - Correct format for Postgres "timestamp with timezone" date format

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I'm querying a Postgres database and looking for the best way to store a Postgres "timestamp with timezone" information.

the format is "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSSzz" (i.e. "2014-04-22 05:39:49.916+03")

i'd like to use a timestamp oriented type/class to keep the info (not String)

the following throws Unparsable date for all the `TIME_FORMATS` i could think of:

```
final String TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz";
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
final java.util.Date utilDate = sdf.parse("2014-04-22 05:39:49.916+03");
```

Comment: in the end i used java.sql.Timestamp and it worked perfectly.
instead of reading the DB content as string and then building a date like above (with @Codebender 's fix - which worked perfectly), i was able to read the DB content (the timestamp) as java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: FYI, that string format you showed is standard SQL date time format. The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines similar formats but replaced the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

Comment: Using `java.sql.Timestamp` is the right way currently. When you update to a [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html) driver, you can dump the java.sql.Timestamp class to use new java.time types instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your format is having `ISO Timezone`, so use `X` (not z).

```
final String TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX";
```

[More Info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: In the end i used DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT.format(Date date); from org.apache.commons.lang3.time

Answer (score 2):

## java.sql.Timestamp

Current JDBC drivers will create. [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object for you when retrieving a value from either of Postgres’ time stamp types, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 ) ;
```

No need for strings. Stick to using objects rather than strings for date-time values whenever possible.

## java.time

In Java 8 and later you should be using the new java.time package. Avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and so on.

When your JDBC driver is updated for [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html), you will be able to retrieve your Postgres date-time value directly into the java.time types.

While waiting on such drivers, use the new conversion methods added to java.sql.Timestamp for going [to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) and [from](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#fromInstant--) an [`Instant`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

Search StackOverflow for more info as this has been discussed many times already.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!, i'm using ibatis, and i'm not sure if it uses the JDBC drivers

Comment: @joeybaruch Do you mean [MyBatis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis)? IBatis is the predecessor, and has been retired. Both are frameworks built on top of JDBC. I'm concerned you are not aware of your JDBC driver. Behavior can vary between drivers as not every detail is spelled out in the JDBC spec. This is especially true for date-time work. You must learn the particular behavior of your driver with your database. Experiment with throwaway code to learn. Do not rely entirely on a framework like MyBatis.

Comment: i am using ibatis, it's proven to be enough for what i need.. 
and yes, i was not aware of my JDBC driver. could you elaborate on  what you meant by "throwaway code", and why not to rely on MyBatis to extract sql data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you could store the data in a [`ZonedDateTime` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), which stores a

> date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

Simple call `toInstant()` on the `java.sql.Timestamp` value in the result and you're good to go (thanks @Basil Bourque for pointing this out).

Prior to Java 8, you could use your existing solution. Note however that if your timezone info is stored as `+03`, you should have your time format pattern end with `X`, which is a ISO 8601 time zone.

Comment: Using `ZonedDateTime` is the way to go, but no need for parsing. Go Postgres > JDBC driver > java.sql.Timestamp > [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) method > `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( Instant , ZoneId )`. No strings attached.  :-)